# How To Display Second Icon on Leaflet Map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I cannot work out how to display two separate icons with pop up data on Leaflet maps. I have written code that can display either one but not both at the same time on the same layer.

This is my code:

```
var map = L.map("map", { scrollWheelZoom: false }).setView(
  [3.143363, 101.712346],
  12
);
new L.Control.Zoom({ position: "bottomleft" }).addTo(map);
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
  subdomains: ["a", "b", "c"],
}).addTo(map);

var myURL = jQuery('script[src$="leafmalaymap1.js"]')
  .attr("src")
  .replace("leafmalaymap1.js", "");

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + "tower2.png",
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14],
});

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {
  L.marker([markers[i].latitude, markers[i].longitude], { icon: myIcon })
    .bindPopup(
      'Location: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].area +
        '</span><br>Hill LRD: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].hillLrd +
        '</span><br>NE Site Name: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].neSiteName +
        '</span><br>NE Latitude: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].latitude +
        '</span><br>NE Longitude: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].longitude +
        '</span><br>NE Site Address: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[i].siteAddress +
        "</span><br>"
    )
    .addTo(map);
}

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + "tower3.png",
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14],
});

for (var o = 0; o < markers.length; ++o) {
  L.marker([markers[o].latitude2, markers[o].longitude2], { icon: myIcon })
    .bindPopup(
      'Bax LRD: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[o].feBaxLrd +
        '</span><br>Baxis Latitude: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[o].latitude2 +
        '</span><br>Bax Longitude: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[o].longitude2 +
        '</span><br>Bax FE Site Address: <span class="mapbold">' +
        markers[o].feSiteAddress +
        "</span><br>"
    )
    .addTo(map);
}
```

If I change the order of `[markers[i]` & `[markers[o]` both will work independently, but do not show simultaneously.

I have tried searched on Stackoverflow but no related issues cropped up.
Really appreciate some guidance on what changes I need to this JS script to make this work

Comment: Could you share a sample of your `markers` array? Are your coordinates for any given marker (latitude-longitude and latitude2-longitude2) very close, or even identical?

Comment: The `myIcon` variable is being defined twice. That should be giving a warning, and fixing that might just get rid of the problem.

Comment: @ghybs Not identical. In some cases they are below 1km, others anything up to 5km in distance. The markers array is not an issue as both can display individually but not together.

Comment: @ IvanSanchez could you expand on that suggestion? I am getting no warnings in "Console" when I check. Should the second one be created as myIcon2 to differentiate it? would this work?

Comment: When you say "_both will work independently, but do not show simultaneously_", what do you mean exactly? Are you expecting 2 popups to open simultaneously when clicking on one of the Markers?

Comment: @ ghybs if I change the order the first set will show and their pop ups will display when clicked. I am trying to get both first & second sets displaying simultaneously, so far I have not achieved this.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I followed your suggestion about myIcon being defined twice and resolved the issue: 
I changed the second myIcon to myIcone and changed the second [markers[i] to [markers[o] and it all worked. 
Thank you so much for your suggestion, it was a simple resolution, but one I could not resolve without your input. 
Much appreciated :-)

Comment: How do I mark this question as answered???

Comment: @MichaelJoseph: write your solution as an _answer_ below and you will be able to accept it, whicj will mark your question as solved.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made the mistake of defining 'myIcon' twice and resolved the issue by changing the second 'myIcon' to 'myIcone' and changed the second [markers[i] to [markers[o] and it all worked.
Many thanks to IvanSanchez who pointed me in the right direction